# Setting a data connection to a datagridview programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to programmatically set the data the appears in a datagridview. The reason I can't use the wizard to do this is because the data in `my.settings.database-string` may vary, however the database structure it points to will always be the same.

```
 Public Sub Config_Datagrid()

        Dim connString As String = My.Settings.Database_String
        Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        ' create a data adapter 
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID, [Name Of Person], [SAP Job Number], [Site Name], [Asset Description], [Spares Supplier], [Supplier Contact Name], [Supplier Contact Phone Number], [Supplier Contact Email], [Spares Description], [Part Number], [Quantity To Order], Cost, [Request Date], [Date Ordered], [Ordered By], [Invoice Received], [Invoice Paid], [Method Of Payment], [Date Item Received], [Additional Comments], [Quote Attatchment] FROM Spares", myConnection)

        ' create a new dataset 
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        ' fill dataset 
        da.Fill(ds, "Spares")

        Main.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager


    End Sub
```

The code executes successfully, but the datagridview simply stays blank. Any ideas?

Comment: I wish I knew why people downvote questions without giving a reason... I'd like to know what's wrong so I can improve my question asking in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill a `DataTable` instead of a `DataSet`:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
' fill dataset 
da.Fill(dt)
```

Or you can use the first `DataTable` in the DataSet:

```
Main.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

The `DataGridView` can only show one `DataTable` at a time. The `DataSet` can contain many `DataTables`.

ADDENDUM:

A third way is to set the `DataMember` property. This is only really useful if your dataset does actually have multiple tables. You still can only show one `DataTable` at a time, though:

```
Dim dst As New DataSet("DST")
Dim dtb0 As New DataTable("T0")
dtb0.Columns.Add("T0C0")
dtb0.Columns.Add("T0C1")
dtb0.Columns.Add("T0C2")
dtb0.Columns.Add("T0C3")
dtb0.Columns.Add("T0C4")
dtb0.Rows.Add("T0R0C0", "T0R0C1", "T0R0C2", "T0R0C3", "T0R0C4")
dtb0.Rows.Add("T0R1C0", "T0R1C1", "T0R1C2", "T0R1C3", "T0R1C4")
dtb0.Rows.Add("T0R2C0", "T0R2C1", "T0R2C2", "T0R2C3", "T0R2C4")

Dim dtb1 As New DataTable("T1")
dtb1.Columns.Add("T1C0")
dtb1.Columns.Add("T1C1")
dtb1.Columns.Add("T1C2")
dtb1.Columns.Add("T1C3")
dtb1.Columns.Add("T1C4")
dtb1.Rows.Add("T1R0C0", "T1R0C1", "T1R0C2", "T1R0C3", "T1R0C4")
dtb1.Rows.Add("T1R1C0", "T1R1C1", "T1R1C2", "T1R1C3", "T1R1C4")
dtb1.Rows.Add("T1R2C0", "T1R2C1", "T1R2C2", "T1R2C3", "T1R2C4")
dst.Tables.Add(dtb0)
dst.Tables.Add(dtb1)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dst
DataGridView1.DataMember = dst.Tables(1).TableName
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew I was close! The `Main.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` worked for me!